# How do I run an Emacs function from the terminal with an argument?

Tags: fonts, functions, command-line-arguments

I want to install icon font for that I need to run `all-the-icons-install-fonts` function. According to the [documentation](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/blob/develop/docs/getting_started.org#install-doom-manually) I have to type: `emacs --batch -f all-the-icons-install-fonts` in the terminal. After that I get the message: "*Symbol's function definition is void: all-the-icons-install-fonts*".

The Emacs help says "*When PFX is non-nil, ignore the prompt and just install*" and that's what I need, but I can't pass any argument to this function because `-f` flag means "*call Emacs Lisp function FUNC with no arguments*".

Is it possible to run this function with an argument or suppress prompt(no questions asked)?

Emacs version: 27.1

Comment: The problem here is that it cannot even find the function that you are trying to call. That's an installation problem: Have you installed the `all-the-icons` package? If yes, how?

Comment: You can't run it at all, because Emacs doesn't recognise it as a function.  You'll need to `load` the library which defines it.  You can do that with the `-l` option.

Comment: @NickD No, I didn't install any extra packages.

Comment: Well, that's the first thing that you have to do: install the `all-the-icons` package. Then invoke emacs as you do, but as @phils points out, you might need to load (with `-l`) a small init file that sets your `load-path` so that emacs can find the `all-the-icons` package and load it.